# Bone rigging incorrectly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I am making a rigged character. When the wrist is lifted up, the whole arm should move, and the torso should not. The correct 'connecting line' from the wrist to the collarbone (may be hard to see, click on the image and it is clearer):

[image]

however the opposite arm's wrist is connected to the pelvis so that when it is raised the whole character tips:

[image]

How do I fix this, and connect the left wrist to the left collarbone, like the right?

Thanks in advance.

here is my .blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** It turns out you have the *Auto IK* option enabled. To turn that off, press <kbd>N</kbd> with your mouse in the 3d view to open up the sidebar and go to the tools tab.

[image]

Uncheck that and you are good to go!

**EDIT:** The information below did not answer the question directly, but may help others as it can cause a very similar issue.

I looks like you just need to adjust the *Chain Length* in the IK constraint, found here:

[image]

What this does is tell Blender how many bones in the chain to use. The default is 0, meaning the whole chain is used, in your case up to the pelvis. I think you would need to set yours to 3, but you'll be able to see the line update as you change the length.

Comment: I don't think I am using IK on my hands, only the legs. Should I create this constraint for both shoulders?

Comment: When a bone is yellow with a dashed line connecting to another bone that means there is an IK constraint. If there wasn't, you wouldn't see any movement in the rig when you move the wrist, the wrist would just rotate. If you select the wrist bone (the yellow one in the second image) you should see an IK constraint in the bone constraints tab (see the image in my answer above). This is the right way to do it, and you wouldn't need to anything to the shoulders. The IK constraint is applied to the bone that you want to use to control the other bones in the arm or leg.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for all your help so far. Yes, it would seem as though there is an IK constraint on the wrist, I can't seem to see it in the inspector. See here: https://imgur.com/a/X01pDkR . I'm still quite new to Blender so I apologise I am am a bit slow

Comment: Perhaps there are doubles of some bones. Try selecting the wrist bone and hiding it with H. Since there are flashes of yellow/orange on certain bones there must be something there. If you don't mind sharing your file, you can also upload it and link to it in your question using this site: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Absolutely! I have stuck it in the question. It doesn't seem like there are any duplicate bones from my `h` press, though I am probably doing it wrong. If all else fails, could I just delete the badly behaving side and mirror it? Though I don't know how this would fix the head...

Comment: I found the issue, and updated the question with the solution.

Comment: I would never have figured that out. You are amazing :) Keep on, dude